# Identifying a key in a dictionary by position

Tags: python, dictionary, key

I'm trying to see if I can identify a key in a dictionary by postion in the dictionary.

So:

```
dict = {'A':[], 'B': [], 'C': []}
```

I want to be able to identify that 'A' is the 0th key in dict, 'B' is the 1st key in dict, and 'C' in the 2nd key in dict etc.

Comment: **Dictionaries are un-ordered**

Comment: What have you already tried yourself to do this? Please review [How much research effort is expected?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users). Stack Overflow is not a coding service. You are expected to research your issue and make a good attempt to write the code yourself before posting. If you get stuck on something specific, come back and include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and a summary of what you tried, so we can help.

Comment: In a standard dict, you cannot be sure of what the order is. If you want to check something like this you might want to use an [Ordered Dict](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#ordereddict-objects)

Answer (score 0):

You can't, dictionaries are unordered containers.

You could, if that made sense to you, sort the `dictionary.keys()`, and access them in sequence, or via their indices.
Or you could `use OrderedDicts` from the `collections module`